# Regarding Sheafification functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, quasicoherent-sheaves

Assume we are in the category of sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Suppose two presheaves maps to the same sheaf under the sheafification functor. Does it imply that two presheaves were same?

I am trying to prove that it should be true. If not then two presheaves have different global sections but global sections of presheaf is contained in global sections of its associated sheaf, which are equal. I am unable to progress further. Any help would be great.

Comment: Since the sheafification functor is the identity of sheaves, the only way your statement could be true is if every presheaf was already a sheaf.

Comment: Here I am saying that is it possible for two different prsheaves to have same associated sheaf? I did not get you point.

Comment: For any presheaf P, if S is the sheafification functor, P and S(P) will be two presheaves that map to the same sheaf, namely S(P).  If your statement were true, then P was already S(P), and so every presheaf would already be a sheaf.

Comment: Ok..thanks I got it.